# Opening external links in already opened browser window

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, settings

The problem is that when I click on link in Telegram or any other app that is not browser(for example, it can be calendar with google meet link) it opens a new browser window, instead of a new tab in already opened window. A new window also has header saying that it is being controlled by automated test software.
It changed with latest chrome update, and I do not know how to revert this.
OS is macos sonoma 14.0
[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXXgY.png)

Comment: This is pretty confusingly written - what exactly are you talking about here?  Are you referring to your use of Telegram within it's client desktop app?  What operating system?  You're giving us far too little information and details to be able to possibly help you.

Comment: @itsamystery I have expanded the explanation